# Why do hashtags in \href not work?

Tags: urls, href

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
   \url{http://mirror.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#toc-Overview-of-LaTeX-1}
\end{document}
```

This code produces a clickable link which does not open correctly in the latest version of Firefox (and Safari). It produces a %23 instead of a # in the url. Manually replacing the %23 with # makes the url work.

How can I make LaTeX create the correct clickable link?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  Do the links work in Acrobat? If so, this is a duplicate of [Hyperlinks to web sites using anchors sometimes don't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/526207/4301)

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, it appears to be a duplicated. I'm happy to close it as such. Thanks.

Comment: A separate comment: Be sure to load the `xurl` package as well (before loading the `hyperref` package) to get better line breaks in long URL strings.